# How to use specific selectors on $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find out how to check if a checkbox is checked or not.

I know about the `:checked` selector but I'm trying to do this using the `$(this)` object.

```
$(".permission_checkbox").live('change',function(){
    if($(this+":checked").length==0){
        alert('remove');
    } else {
        alert('add');
    }
});
```

This code always calls `alert('add')`!

Thanks for any help & merry christmas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`jQuery.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$(this).is(":checked")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `is` is the best option for a condition (`if`). `filter` might also be mildly useful if you want to operate on `this`, but not in this case.

Comment: this works fine and is more clear than other answers so I'll select this !

Answer (score 4):

While you asked about using selectors, you really don't need jQuery for this.

Checkboxes have a `checked` property you can access directly, which will be much faster than adding the overhead of *jQuery object creation + method call + selector engine*.

```
if( this.checked ) {
    // it was checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$(this).find(':checked')
```

Comment: This only finds children of `$(this)`, which are checked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `+` you should use shortcut for find  `$(":checked", this)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to select the checked input.

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

hope it will help..